# Start string on position x

Tags: c#, string

I have a question.
Is it possible to start on specific position without adding spaces into string.

```
string position4 = "Position4";
string position5 = "Position5";
string positiontogether = position4 + position5;
```

And outcome would be like this

```
"    Position4"
"     Position5"
"    Position4     Position5"
```

EDIT2:
I try to clarify.
Lets say thats position4 is random length string and position5 starts always on 20. positsion in string.

```
"position4           positsion5"

"position412         positsion5"

"positioasdjsdsdadsdspositsion5"
```

Added EDIT to clarify how position5 need always needs to be on one position.

Comment: What do you mean "start on specific position"?  What would be there if not spaces?

Comment: I don't understand, if your strings have leading whitespaces, string concatenation _already_ gives you that result you want. Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: Simply concatenate a string containing a desired number of spaces with your string.

Comment: What if `position4` is bigger or equal than `20` character?

Comment: @SonerGönül  
Never happens becuase it has maximum string length by standart, but it can be shorter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to use PadRight and specify the total length, e.g.

"Position4".PadRight(20) + "Position5"

Thanks @Ivan Stoev for an Answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`String.PadLeft`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft(v=vs.110).aspx)

> String.PadLeft Method
>
> Returns a new
>   string of a specified length in which the beginning of the current
>   string is padded with spaces or with a specified Unicode character.

Thus, your code would become something like so:

```
string position4 = "Position4".PadLeft(4, ' ');
string position5 = "Position5".PadLeft(5, ' ');
string positionTogether = position4 + position5;
```

Comment: if string is variable like it can be `Position33` or `Position7`. then i think you should take the last number with regex. like `\d+$` and then pad left with amount of matched number. (btw not my vote).

Comment: never mind. the edit to question made it more unclear.

Comment: Didnt downvote, but  I need position5 always start on 10 postision, but positsion4 can always be diffrent lengths

Comment: @Jyrgen what if position 4 is 12? then position 5 cant start from 10 because it will get mixed

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary position 4 has maximum length by standart but it can be shorter

Comment: @Jyrgen Actually you need `PadRight` and specify the total length, e.g. `"Position4".PadRight(20) + "Position5"`. Just read the documentation.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks its the most closest tip i have gotten, but if i have diffrent string length for postision 4 then position 5 is not on the same place :(                                                                                                            "Positsion41    Positsion5"                                                                                  "Postision423 Positsion5"

Comment: @IvanStoev Sorry thanks, i did something wrong it does work.

Answer (score 0):

You do not specially need the space, but if you do not add the space, you must add something else.
The notion of nothing does not exist in the world of computer science. You want to start the meaninful part of your string at position 5, there need to be something before position 5, if you like it or not.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: @roryap, why is it not an answer? If he does not have the space there,. he needs to add something else I thing. Maybe I am wrong, just let me know.

Comment: Well, it started out more as a comment with very little actual substantive content.  But I still think your answer is "not useful", which is one reason to down vote (hover over the down vote button).  There is nothing really to back up what you're stating.  In fact, the notion of "nothing" *does* exist in the world of computer science: `null` is one example.  I also think your answer is worded a little confusingly.  "if you do not add space, you must add something else" <--- why?  why does *anything* need to be added?  You don't explain what you mean by that.

Comment: @roryap, I agree that the wording can not always be meaningful to all. Still the null is not the equivalence of nothing. Because the null is a mark and as such is something that can be interpreted and depend on who coded it. But let us no go into philosophy, it won't help.